# How get list of objects with post request to retrofit 2.1.0 with android

Tags: php, android, post, request, retrofit

I'm new to Android programming and working with Retrofit.

I see many examples to retrofit library, making `GET` requests, passing parameters and bringing all objects on a page in `PHP`.
It is possible, do the same thing with `POST`?
I want to bring all data (`JSON` objects) from my `webservice`, passing the parameters via `POST`, but I can not do the implementation.

Has anyone done or has an example to help me?

Studying the documentation and see examples here in stackoverflow, I could make the example below, but only returns the first object.

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

MainActivity (inside the button):

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.101.36/json/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

    Call<User> call = apiService.validateUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(), inputSenha.getText().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            //Verifica se houve a conexão com sucesso ao webservice
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                textView.setText("ERROR onResponde: " + response.code());
            } else {
                //requisição retona os dados com sucesso
                String email = response.body().getEmail();
                String senha = response.body().getPassword();
                textView.append("email: " + email + " - password: " + senha + "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            textView.setText(t.getMessage());
        }

    });
```

Interface:

```
public interface ApiService {
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("index.php") 
   Call<User> validateUser(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password
   );
}
```

Class User:

```
public class User {
private String  username, email, password;

public String getUsername(){
    return this.username;
}

public String getPassword(){
    return this.password;
}

public String getEmail(){
    return this.email;
}
}
```

Index.php:

```
$email = $_POST['username'];
$senha = $_POST['password'];

if ($email == "manoelps@live.com") {

  echo '
  {
    "email":"' . $email . '",
    "password":"' . $senha . '"
  },
  {
    "email":"myemail@live.com",
    "password":"654321"
  },
  {
    "email":"joselito@joselito.com",
    "password":"123456"
  }
  ';

} else {

  echo '
  {
    "email":"otheremail@otheremail.com",
    "password":"987654"
  },
  {
    "email":"otheremail@otheremail.com",
    "password":"987654"
  },
  {
    "email":"otheremail@otheremail.com",
    "password":"987654"
  }
  ';
}
```

If i use as array of objects ocurred error in the app:

```
[{
"email":"manoelps@live.com",
"password":"123456"
},
{
"email":"manoelps@live.com",
"password":"123456"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, for those who need it, my callback looks like this:

```
        Call<List<User>> call = apiService.validateUser(inputEmail.getText().toString(), inputSenha.getText().toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<java.util.List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                //Verifica se houve a conexão com sucesso ao webservice
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textView.setText("ERROR onResponde: " + response.code());
                } else {

                    try {

                        //pegando os dados
                        List<User> listUsers = response.body();

                        //retona os dados
                        for (User c : listUsers) {
                            textView.append("Email: " + c.getEmail() + " - " + "Senha: " + c.getPassword() + "\n");
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        textView.setText("ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect multiple returns you need to specify that your call returns a list.

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("index.php") 
   Call<User> validateUser(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password
   );
```

should be

```
   @FormUrlEncoded
   @POST("index.php") 
   Call<List<User>> validateUser(
        @Field("username") String username,
        @Field("password") String password
   );
```

Then in your callback `response.body()` will give you a list of User objects you can iterate through.

Comment: Ben, my dear, very very thank you!
It worked 100%, it was suffering the week.